# ¿Como ingresar un contador dentro del while?

Tags: php

si me pueden colaborar de como podría ingresar un contador dentro del while, la idea es al momento lo filtre por un rango de fechas me muestra la  informacion en caso contrario si esta por fuera no me los muestre si me puede colaborar muchas gracias.

aca esta el codigo

```
<?php
require_once('../conexion/conexion.php');

// echo "hola";
$id_convenios =$_POST['id_convenios'];
$bus =$_POST['bus'];
$fechai =$_POST['fechai'];
$fechaf =$_POST['fechaf'];

$sql = "SELECT   ca.id_campanas,
ca.nombre,
esc.nombre estado_campanas,
co.nombre convenios,
ca.presupuesto,
ca. fc
   FROM campanas ca 
   INNER JOIN estado_campanas esc ON esc.id_estadoc = ca.id_estadoc
   INNER JOIN convenios co ON co.id_convenios = ca.id_convenios
   WHERE  ca.nombre like '%$bus%'
   AND ca.id_convenios = '$id_convenios' 
   AND ca.estado = 'Activo'
   AND date(`fecha_i`) BETWEEN date('$fechai') AND date('$fechaf')
   ";
echo "</br>";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

  echo "</br>";
    echo '<table class="table table-hover">

           <a class="align-middle">
              <thead>
              <tr style="background:#e1e2e6;">
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre Estado de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre del Convenio</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Presupuesto</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Fecha de Creación</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>';    
              $filas=0;

              while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
             {
                if($filas<0){    
                  echo "<tr>
                  <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[nombre] </td>
                  <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[estado_campanas]</td>
                  <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[convenios]</td>
                  <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[presupuesto]</td>
                  <td style='text-align: center'>$filas[fc]</td>
             </tr>";
             $filas++;
                } 

                else {
                  echo "no se encontraron resultados";
                }
              } 
               echo "</table> <br> </div>";
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo por qué quieres filtrar dentro del `while`, ¿acaso ya los datos no vienen filtrados en la consulta al usar `BETWEEN`? Y en cuanto a la consulta SQL: ¿la columna `fecha_i` no es acaso de tipo `DATE`  o `DATETIME`? ¿por qué intentas convertirla a `date` de nuevo aquí: `AND date(`fecha_i`) BETWEEN ...` ?

Comment: si pero la idea es por ejemplo me busque el dato dentro de un rango de fechas estipulados por ejemplo: si un informe fue creado el 10/10/2018 y finalizo el 20/10/2018 la idea es que muestre el dato de acuerdo al rango que esta estipulado en caso contrario sino me dija que no haya resultados  ya que esta por fuera del rango

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es verficar la cantidad de filas que trajo la consulta. Si es `0` indica que no trajo resultados. No tiene sentido intentar leer una consulta vacía...

Comment: lo que pasa lo estoy haciendo es para que muestre la informacion que tengo registrada en el base de datos ya que estoy realizando un buscador o de que manera lo podria hacer para que me traiga la informacion de acuerdo a las fechas  y si esta por fuera del rango me dija no hay resultados  muchas gracias si me puede colaborar

Comment: Te lo estoy explicando. El `BETWEEN`  sirve para eso. Si por ejemplo tú pones `WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-10' AND '2018-10-15'`  te traerá los registros cuyo valor en la columna `fecha` esté entre el `10` y el `15`  de octubre. Luego puedes verificar si esa consulta trajo `0` filas, lo cual querrá decir que no hay fechas entre esa rango. ¿No es eso lo que quieres o es otra cosa? Es que tu forma de plantear la pregunta es algo confusa.

Comment: Parece que te convendría utilizar un bucle `for` contando la longitud del array.

Answer (score 1):

Fácil yo lo tengo así:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
echo $i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido bien tu problema, porque, como ha apuntado alguien, tu pregunta es un poco confusa. Sin embargo, dos cosas.

Lo primero, donde pones if ($filas < 0). En ese escenario, esa condición no se va a cumplir nunca. El número de respuestas de una consulta será 0, o mayor, pero nunca menor.

La segunda. Asegúrate de que las fechas lleguen a la consulta en el formato ISO 8601 extendido, o tu acotación no funcionará. Echa un vistazo en https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Answer (score 0):

Sin entrar en algunos detalles como el método que utilizas para leer los resultados, que yo haría de otra manera comprobando si ha habido algún error, etc., creo que lo que pretendes hacer es mostrar las filas si hay resultados, y si no hay registros que se vea el mensaje correspondiente.

La base de uno de los problemas es que utilizas la variable $filas para almacenar tanto cada una de las filas, como el supuesto contador de filas leídas. Yo he usado una para el primer caso (`$fila_actual`) y otra para el contador (`$num_filas`)
He retocado tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php
    require_once('../conexion/conexion.php');

    // echo "hola";
    $id_convenios =$_POST['id_convenios'];
    $bus =$_POST['bus'];
    $fechai =$_POST['fechai'];
    $fechaf =$_POST['fechaf'];

    $sql = "SELECT   ca.id_campanas,
    ca.nombre,
    esc.nombre estado_campanas,
    co.nombre convenios,
    ca.presupuesto,
    ca. fc
    FROM campanas ca 
    INNER JOIN estado_campanas esc ON esc.id_estadoc = ca.id_estadoc
    INNER JOIN convenios co ON co.id_convenios = ca.id_convenios
    WHERE  ca.nombre like '%$bus%'
    AND ca.id_convenios = '$id_convenios' 
    AND ca.estado = 'Activo'
    AND date(`fecha_i`) BETWEEN date('$fechai') AND date('$fechaf')
    ";
    echo "</br>";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    echo "</br>";
    echo '<table class="table table-hover">

            <a class="align-middle">
            <thead>
            <tr style="background:#e1e2e6;">
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre Estado de la Campaña</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Nombre del Convenio</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Presupuesto</th>
                    <th style="color: #1674ae;text-align: center;">Fecha de Creación</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>';    
    $num_filas=0;

    while ($fila_actual = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td style='text-align: center'>".$fila_actual['nombre']."</td>
                    <td style='text-align: center'>".$fila_actual['estado_campanas']."</td>
                    <td style='text-align: center'>".$fila_actual['convenios']."</td>
                    <td style='text-align: center'>".$fila_actual['presupuesto']."</td>
                    <td style='text-align: center'>".$fila_actual['fc']."</td>
                    </tr>";
            $num_filas++;
    } 
    if ($num_filas == 0) 
    {
        echo "<tr>
            <td colspan="5" style='text-align: center'>No se encontraron resultados</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table> <br> </div>";
    ?>
```